# Postgres full text search: Multiple columns, cross table

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

I am new to Postgres and came across full text search feature. I want to achieve the following:

- Specify some table and fields to search on.
- When the user search for some text, it should be searched on above specified table fields.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE customer (name text)
CREATE TABLE address (city text)
```

Search for 'Ram' should find both name 'Ram*' and city 'Ram*' (may be max 10 records).

Open point: Ranking.

I understand it might not be straighfoward, but if you can provide example statements to achieve similar?

Comment: How do you propose to return the results of searching two unrelated tables? Do you want to return rows like `(tablename, table_row_id, matching_column, matching_text)`? Try editing your question and adding a real example of what you want: Dummy table definitions and data, and the output you want to achieve.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is covered quite well in the [PostgreSQL documentation on full-text search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/textsearch.html), which shows examples of searching multiple columns and weighting them.

See in particular [controlling full-text search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/textsearch-controls.html) and [manipulating documents](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/textsearch-features.html#TEXTSEARCH-MANIPULATE-TSVECTOR). Ranking is also right there, in [ranking search results](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-RANKING).

You haven't really provided enough information to say much more. For searching across multiple tables you usually want to `JOIN` the tables then query them, or, for best performance, create a trigger-maintained materialized view that you can index and then query that.

If the tables are independent and unrelated it doesn't make tons of sense to query them in a single query; you'd usually use multiple tsearch2 queries for this. I guess it's possible that you could `UNION ALL` the query results then rank them, but there's no guarantee the ranking would be consistent between the two tables.